# Handling button in multiple Cards

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I've product listing page where I use multiple `ProductCard` component. I need to add `Spinner` to Add to cart button when clicking on it, but if I just add `Spinner` to `v-else` I've `Spinners` in every `ProductCard`. How to control only this `ProductCard` where I click Add to cart button?

Parent's component:

```
<ProductCard
  v-for="product in products"
  :key="product.id"
  :product="product"
/>
```

Child's component:

```
<template>
  <div id="productCart">
    <div>
      <NuxtLink :to="`/product/${item.slug}`" />
      <NuxtLink v-if="item.name" :to="`/product/${item.slug}`">
        <h5
          id="productName"
          v-text="item.name"
        />
      </NuxtLink>
      <Button
        v-if="!loading"
        @click="addToBuyCart({ product: item })"
        v-text="$t('labels.buy')"
      />
      <Spinner v-else />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

`loading` is defined in composable, and it's updating in addToBuyCart function by making it true, then adding to cart (api), then making it false

Comment: where is `loading` defined and how it is updated?

Comment: @IgorMoraru it's defined in composable, and it is updating in addToBuyCart function by making it true, then adding to cart (api), then making it false

Comment: Instead of using a Boolean you can use a Number and put there `product.id` After that it is trivial for any Button to check whether it should spin or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by IVO, in such situations you should check against a value specific for each item in the loop, item ID for example, instead of a boolean which lacks specificity and therefore cannot be used for such scenarios.

```javascript
<template>
  <div id="productCart">
    <div>
      <NuxtLink :to="`/product/${item.slug}`" />
      <NuxtLink v-if="item.name" :to="`/product/${item.slug}`">
        <h5
          id="productName"
          v-text="item.name"
        />
      </NuxtLink>
      <Button
        v-if="loading !== item.id"
        @click="addToBuyCart({ product: item })"
        v-text="$t('labels.buy')"
      />
      <Spinner v-else />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

const addToBuyCart = ({product}) => {
  loading = product.id
  // some logic or request
  loading = null
}
```